# Shutdown of remote computers not working

Tags: vbscript, shutdown

I am writing a script for a class that will look at every computer on the network and then shutdown each computer.  I have the first part of the script working. However, the second part of the script doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Here is the part of the Script that is not working.

```
Sub shutdown
  'Open a text file of computer names with one computer name per line
  'get the next computer name store it in variable strMachine
  'go through the text file
  const READ=1
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set objFile = fso.GetFile("c:\comp230\computers.txt")

  If objFile.size > 0 Then
    Set objReadFile=fso.openTextFile("c:\comp230\computers.txt", READ)
    Do Until objReadFile.AtEndOfStream
      strline = objReadFile.ReadLine()
      'If strMachine = Vlab-PC1 Then 
        'Exit Do
      'End If
      Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      WshShell.Run "cmd.exe  /c shutdown -s -f -m" & strline & " /c " & _
        strWarning & " /t " & strDelay, 0, False
    Loop
    objReadFile.Close
  End If
  'close the text file
End Sub
```

I have narrowed down the problem to this line:

```
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe  /c shutdown -s -f -m" & strline & " /c " & _
  strWarning & " /t " & strDelay, 0, False
```

Comment: Do `/arg` style switches work better for you? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91fd97b0-44ae-4623-8312-441f29f8705b/shutdown-command-cmd-not-working?forum=W8ITProPreRel

Comment: I've tried both `/arg` and `-arg` and it seems neither one work.  But your article did bring up something that my script is doing.  It is looping the `WScript.Echo(" Shutdown Complete")` in a pop up window, even though I'm executing it through CScript in the CLI.

Comment: Are you missing a space between  -m and the computer name? Instead of running the command, output it to the screen and try running it from a cmd as is to see if it works. I think it's a syntax issue in the command, not a VBS issue.

Comment: `"cmd.exe /c shutdown -s -f -m \\" & strline & " /c """ & strWarning & """ /t " & strDelay` @Bob is right. Syntax of questionable `shutdown` switches is `/m \\computer` and `/c "comment"`. Not much more to tell knowing nothing about `strline`, `strWarning` and `strDelay`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you need a space the parameters of the `shutdown` command require a space between them and their argument. From the [command help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx):

> **Syntax**
>   `shutdown [{-l|-s|-r|-a}] [-f] [-m [\\ComputerName]] [-t xx] [-c "message"] [-d[u][p]:xx:yy]`
>
> **Parameters**
>   […]
>   **-m [ \\ ComputerName ] :** Specifies the computer that you want to shut down.
>   **-t   xx   :** Sets the timer for system shutdown in xx seconds. The default is 20 seconds.
>   **-c   " message "   :** Specifies a message to be displayed in the Message area of the System Shutdown window. You can use a maximum of 127 characters. You must enclose the message in quotation marks.

Whether you use the form `-p` or `/p` is irrelevant, `shutdown.exe` accepts both.

If you provide IP addresses as arguments for the parameter `-m` the leading `\\` are not required, and the double quotes around the argument for the parameter `-c` are only required if the text contains spaces. They won't hurt otherwise, though.

Also, running the command with `cmd.exe` is optional, since `shutdown` is an executable (not a CMD builtin command like `dir`), and you don't use anything CMD-specific, like output redirection.

Basically, your shutdown commandline should look like this:

```
"shutdown -s -f -m " & strline & " -c """ & strWarning & """ -t " & strDelay
```

or (if you're using hostnames instead of IP addresses) like this:

```
"shutdown -s -f -m \\" & strline & " -c """ & strWarning & """ -t " & strDelay
```

---

On a more general note, when troubleshooting external commands in a VBScript it's always a good idea to build the command string in a separate variable, so you can echo it in order to a) inspect it for syntactical correctness and b) verify that the inserted values actually are what you expect them to be:

```
cmd = "shutdown -s -f -m " & strline & ...
WScript.Echo cmd
WshShell.Run cmd, 0, False
```

If the command produces errors or other output relevant for troubleshooting you need to make its window visible and prevent it from automatically being closed. Run the command with `cmd /k` and set the 2nd parameter to `1`, so you can inspect the output it generates:

```
WshShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k " & cmd, 1, True
```

Running the command synchronously (3rd parameter set to `True`) prevents loops from flooding your desktop with command windows.

An alternative to displaying the window is to redirect the output to a log file:

```
WshShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & cmd & " >> ""C:\path\to\your.log"" 2>&1", 0, True
```

`>>` appends to the log file (so it doesn't get overwritten in a loop), and `2>&1` includes error output. On the rare occasion that a program generates output on handles other than STDOUT (1) and STDERR (2) you need to [redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb490982) those as well (`3>&1`, `4>&1`, …). You'll still want to run the command synchronously here to avoid concurrent write access to the log file.

Comment: Thank you guys!!!  You are a life saver!!  I thought the variable strline contained the // in the string, turns out it wasn't.  So by adding the space and the // in the shutdown command made it work.  Thanks again!!!